# Arreglo de objetos Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

me pasa algo muy curioso, resulta que mi código genera un arreglo y otro sub arreglo con los usuarios integrantes de dicha publicación. El problema esta en la parte de la generación de los usuarios, concretamente el llenado de **arrayOfUser** me esta llenando el arreglo sin indices y al tratar de recorrerlo no me permite llegar al segundo registro, solo muestra el primero. Alguna forma de recorrerlo y genere los indices? Gracias, quedo atento.

```
static test2(idUsuario, callback){
    const Publicaciones = firebaseApp.database().ref("/contenido/publicaciones/")
    // var Integrantes = ""
    let arrayOfServices = []
    let arrayOfUser = []
    Publicaciones.on('value', function (snapshot) {
        let data = snapshot.val();
        arrayOfServices = []
        if(data){
            for(let key in data){
                let obj = data[key]
                let integrantes = obj.integrantes || null
                let solicitudes = obj.solicitudes || null
                let idUserMaster = obj.idUsuario
                if(idUsuario === idUserMaster){
                    if(integrantes !== null){
                        Object.values(integrantes).map((item) => {
                                firebaseApp.database().ref("/contenido/user/" + item.idUsuario).on('value', function(snapshot2) {
                                    let data2 = snapshot2.val();
                                    if(data2){
                                        arrayOfUser.push({
                                            name: data2.name, 
                                            idUsuario: item.idUsuario
                                        });
                                    }
                                })
                        })
                        arrayOfServices.push({
                            integrantes,
                            solicitudes,
                            cupos_pasajeros,
                            titulo,
                            url_portada,
                            id,
                            estado_viaje,
                            estado,
                            descripcion,
                            arrayOfUser
                        })
                    }

                }

            }
            // console.log(arrayOfServices)
            callback(arrayOfServices)
        }
    });
}
```

/**********RESULTADO****************/

```
{
  "solicitudes": null,
  "cupos_pasajeros": "2",
  "titulo": "Mochileo hasta chiloé",
  "id": "-M5ivrqL4XMxI3dYokP0",
  "estado_viaje": "1",
  "estado": "1",
  "arrayOfUser": [
    {
      "name": "Jose Unda",
      "idUsuario": "HDMiHRhS2oQ32sNHvde8bXitzAs1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Paola",
      "idUsuario": "W1fQvOYOATXIiNEj0hG07339sIe2"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "integrantes": null,
  "solicitudes": null,
  "cupos_pasajeros": "3",
  "titulo": "Viaje en moto",
  "id": "1587521884670",
  "estado_viaje": "1",
  "estado": "1",
  "arrayOfUser": null
}
```

Comment: Object.values(integrantes).map((item, indice) puedes usar el indice de map

Comment: Cuando recorro con MAP y le paso el indice, item[indice] me devuelve undefined, pero si paso solo item, console.log(item), me devulve el primer registro. 
Resultado:
{
  "name": "Jose Unda",
  "idUsuario": "HDMiHRhS2oQ32sNHvde8bXitzAs1"
}

Comment: @Jose si recorres con map no debes usar item[indice] puesto que indice se refiere al valor numerico, pero recuerda en un objeto es muy improbable que existan propiedades numericas, los indices numericos en un objeto servirian para otros propositos, debes usar simplemente item, asi nada mas, un objeto no usa indices numericos, o por lo menos no normalmente, los objetos usan indices asociativos (indices nombrables).

Comment: @Riven gracias por la aclaración, de todas formas al momento de recorrer los objetos solo me devuelve el primero, trae 2 objetos pero al usar length dice que su longitud es de 1, cuando trae 2 objetos. Como se logra apreciar en el resultado, el arreglo arrayOfUser trae 2 registros pero sin un indice para recorrerlo, asumo que ese es el error, sino, estoy super perdido. Gracias.